# How to load OSM data to RDS instance (PostgreSQL) on AWS

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I am trying to load the OSM data to PostgreSQL (RDS on AWS). I could not find any information on loading the OSM data to cloud. I tried the steps outlined in many website and osm2pgsql but nothing seems to work.

Any pointers?

Comment: osm2pgsql should work - it's just a server. have you tried other data import tools such as QGIS to load a shapefile?

Comment: can you post the command you're using and any error messages?